# Improving WPF application performance with UI being updated every 100ms

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application. I would like to explain the working of the application. The application is used for monitoring data that is received over network through UDP, every 100 ms. In the application's main window, another thread is started in which the UPD packets are received and parsed. After the data is parsed, the packet based on packet ID is updated to UI through dispatcher. There are 5 windows with a browser control, couple of charts and text boxes in each window.

The UI rendering is slow and application responsiveness reduces when more than one window at a time is updated. What is the best way to improve the performance of the application? Is it good if each of the window is created in a new thread? If each window is created in a new thread, I have noticed that some data is missing in the UI. Moreover, setting the owner of these windows to the main window is also not possible which is proving to be a problem.

Comment: what is the bottleneck? have you profiled the performance with some tool?

Comment: I have 3 charts in each window with 4 line series each.

Comment: how much time is spent on receiving a UDP packet? and how much time is spent on updating to UI?